# Getting Promise<fullfield> in return

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I am adding bunch of promises in an array

```
    const apiCallsToMake = [];
     apiCallsToMake.push(this.getDataFromUnsplash(copyInputParams));
     apiCallsToMake.push(this.getDataFromPexels(copyInputParams));
     apiCallsToMake.push(this.getDataFromPixabay(copyInputParams));
    return Promise.all(apiCallsToMake).then((response) => response);
```

where my getDataFromUnsplash looks like this

```
 async getDataFromUnsplash(params: UNSPLASH): Promise<IMAGE_RESPONSE> {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${upload_base_url}/search/photos`, {
        params,
      });
      const { results } = data;
      const images = await results.map(async (image: any) => {
        const imgData = {
          id: image.id,
          url: image.urls.raw,
        };
        if (this.includeBlob) {
          const image_blob = await fetch(image.urls.raw).then(r => r.blob());
          return { ...imgData, image_blob }
        }
        return imgData
      });
      return { name: "unsplash", images };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return { name: "unsplash", error };
    }
  }
```

Where type for IMAGE_RESPONSE is

```
export interface IMAGE_DATA {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  url: string;
  name: string;
  id: string;
  siza_small_url: string;
  image_blob?: Blob
}

export interface IMAGE_RESPONSE {
  name: SERVICENAME;
  images?: Array<IMAGE_DATA>;
  error?: any;
}
```

when i console.log data recieved from `romise.all(apiCallsToMake).then((response) => response);`, I am getting promises i.e

```
images: (10) [Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]
name: "unsplash
```

or

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
1: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
2: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
3: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
4: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
5: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
6: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
7: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
8: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
9: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
```

Can someone tell me why thi sis happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: Uh, `apiCallsToMake` will contain only a single promise, the one that the one `getDataFromUnsplash` call returns? You don't need a `Promise.all` call there. You need it inside the `getDataFromUnsplash` function, where `results.map(…)` produces an array of promises.

Comment: @Bergi No, it would contain many promises. (updating question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your map is returning an array of promises, you need to unwrap them in the next stage

```
 async getDataFromUnsplash(params: UNSPLASH): Promise<IMAGE_RESPONSE> {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${upload_base_url}/search/photos`, {
        params,
      });
      const { results } = data;
      const imagePromises = results.map(async (image: any) => {
        const imgData = {
          id: image.id,
          url: image.urls.raw,
        };
        if (this.includeBlob) {
          const image_blob = await fetch(image.urls.raw).then(r => r.blob());
          return { ...imgData, image_blob }
        }
        return imgData
      });
      const images = await Promise.all(imagePromises)
      return { name: "unsplash", images };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return { name: "unsplash", error };
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, This gives following error: `Type '[unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown]' is not assignable to type 'IMAGE_DATA[]'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IMAGE_DATA'` (updating question with IMAGE_DATA type)

Comment: @HardikKhanna That's weird, where do these `unknown`s come from? But yeah, the `imgData` you've shown does not implement the `IMAGE_DATA` interface.

Comment: okay, I fixed by changing the map line to something like this `const imagesPromises: Array<IMAGE_DATA> = results.map(async (image: any): Promise<IMAGE_DATA> => {`

Thanks a lot @Bergi and Eugen

Comment: But that's wrong. It would need to be `const imagePromises: Array<Promise<IMAGE_DATA>> = …`